# How to restyle the draggers of the SplitLayoutPanel in GWT UIBinder template #2

Tags: java, gwt

I am really stuck on redesigning the `SplitLayoutPanel` draggers of `gwt`. My main concern is to change their color.
I already tried this solution: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845291/how-to-restyle-the-draggers-of-the-splitlayoutpanel-in-gwt-uibinder-template) but I could not get it to work.
I use `GWT 2.6` as Eclipse Plugin with the `UIBinder`.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of searching and trying i finally found the answer (wich is of course quite similar to the mentioned one).
I forgot to add the

> .gwt-SplitLayoutPanel{}

to the css.

Here is my code snipped:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM 'http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent'>
<ui:UiBinder
xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"

<ui:style>
@external .gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-HDragger;
@external .gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-VDragger;

.menuBar {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-color:red;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: black;
}
.gwt-SplitLayoutPanel {
}

.gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-VDragger {
    background: #228899 url(img/Hdragger.png) center center no-repeat;
    cursor: row-resize;
}
    .gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-HDragger {
    background: #228899 url(img/Vdragger.png) center center no-repeat;
    cursor: col-resize;
}
</ui:style>
<g:DockLayoutPanel  unit="EM">
<g:north size="3">
  <!-- ...some Widget-->
</g:north>
<g:center>
  <g:SplitLayoutPanel styleName='{style.gwt-SplitLayoutPanel}' ui:field="splitLayoutPanel">
    <g:west size="270">
       <!-- ...some Widget-->
    </g:west>
...
```

Don't forget the following two lines, without these it dosnt work!

```
@external .gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-HDragger;
@external .gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-VDragger;
```

The following Part is to display the draggers, it is optional:

```
url(img/Vdragger.png) center center no-repeat;
```